# .toggleClass() function not working correctly on very quick clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

```js
$(document).on("click", ".collapse-icon", async(event) => { //TreeView Collapse Control
  let collapse_icon = await $(event.target).closest("span").siblings(".collapse");
  await $(collapse_icon).collapse("toggle");
  await $(event.target).toggleClass('fa-plus-circle fa-minus-circle');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>

<body>
  <li class="tree-parent-wrapper tree-last-node">
    <span class="collapse-wrapper">
            <i class="fa fa-plus-circle collapse-icon"></i>
        </span>
    <span class="tree-resource-name">Permissions</span>
    <ol class="tree-permission-wrapper collapse">
      <li style="list-style-type:square;" class="ms-2">read</li>
      <li style="list-style-type:square;" class="ms-2">edit</li>
      <li style="list-style-type:square;" class="ms-2">delete</li>
      <li style="list-style-type:square;" class="ms-2">update</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</body>

</html>
```

If I click plus-icon multiple times very quickly the flow breaks and its starts working opposite.When it has to show minus-icon it starts showing plus-icon and vice-versa.What am I doing wrong and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Why do you need to use async/await on that event handler?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work properly because the class toggling of the `.collapse-icon` doesn't wait for the collapsable items to finish rendering.

A way to make it work properly, is to consider the `show` class name of the collapsable items when deciding the class name of the `collapse-icon` element.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".collapse-icon", (event) => { //TreeView Collapse Control
  const $target = $(event.target);
  const $collapsable = $target.closest('span').siblings('.collapse');
  const isShown = $collapsable.hasClass('show');

  $collapsable.collapse('toggle');

  $target.toggleClass('fa-plus-circle', isShown);
  $target.toggleClass('fa-minus-circle', !isShown);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>

<body>
  <li class="tree-parent-wrapper tree-last-node">
    <span class="collapse-wrapper">
            <i class="fa fa-plus-circle collapse-icon"></i>
        </span>
    <span class="tree-resource-name">Permissions</span>
    <ol class="tree-permission-wrapper collapse">
      <li style="list-style-type:square;" class="ms-2">read</li>
      <li style="list-style-type:square;" class="ms-2">edit</li>
      <li style="list-style-type:square;" class="ms-2">delete</li>
      <li style="list-style-type:square;" class="ms-2">update</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Didn't work.I ran your code snippet.Still Same Problem

Comment: are you sure? Because I can't reproduce it anymore on SO snippet

Comment: I have added image in question with same

Comment: Indeed, it happens, but it is very hard to reproduce. I succeeded to reproduce it, but after many tries, that means that it doesn't matter that much :)

Comment: okay.Just wanted to know if there was a reasonable explanation for it.Thanks